# Google Drive SDK, How to check if a file has been shared outside of the domain by using Permission feed

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive SDK for .NET. Everything is working as expected, except that whenever I get the permission feed for a particular document. I get the Id, kind, name, role, selflink and type fields on permission.

There is no mention of the email address of the user which is stopping me from recognizing by reading the permissions, whether a file has been shared inside the domain or outside of the domain.

I can't use Google Docs API to get the ACL on doc because I am writing an app for users over 200000 users and I will need speed which is provided by Google API Console.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to prevent users from sharing outside of the domain, you can do this in admin setting. http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60781

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Documents List API to get the email addresses. I'm curious why you believe Drive is faster than Documents List, for most API calls they have a comparable response time.

```
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_the_acl_for_a_document_file_or_collection
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea but can I use Document List API with the Service Accounts provided through API Console?

Why do I believe that Google Drive SDK is better? Because we don't have any control over Document List API where we can set QPS (Query per second) limits or not that I know of.

Secondly, with Document List API when you make request to servers, in the past I had to create a fault tollerent algorithm in such a way that if one request fails second should go after 2 seconds if that fails then make your next request after 5 seconds until 7 second delay.

So, I don't think that Document List API would be a good fit for processing documents over 200000 users everyday unless Google has changed the way their API used to behave?